# Sql query to add Zero between string with character and digits

Tags: sql, sql-server

What will be the generic sql query to update id by adding zeros in id. containing alphabets as well as numbers? In between the character and digits 00 needs to be padded e.g QTX23675  should turn into QTX0023675

```
UPDATE Table
    SET QID = 'QTX0023675'
    WHERE QID='QTX23675';
```

There are many records to update and i found query with leading zeros. 
Tried with spliting the string.

Comment: This question is not very clear...

Comment: Is the string format always the same? i.e. always needs to be inserted at position 4 in the string or does it vary?

Comment: do u always have 3 letters as suffix ?

Comment: As @MisterPositive pointed out, the quesiton isn't clear.  You've not defined a pattern so we don't know where the split needs to occur.  Could you have a string with 8 text values so it just adds 2 zeros at the end?  Could you have one with no text so it adds zero's just at the front?  is the final result always 10 characters?  Could it be more than 2 zeros are needed to be added?  too many unknowns.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This to make the result Dynamic

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT Val = 'XTP231'
)
SELECT 
    *,
    NewVal = SUBSTRING(Val,1,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Val)-1)+'00'+SUBSTRING(Val,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',Val),LEN(Val))
    FROM CTE
```

THe Output is as follows

[image: Sample Result]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I m using SQL server. And the pattern is always same: 3 character 5 digits and always needs to be inserted at position 4 in the string.

Comment: Still, you can use this. To Be safe in case of any pattern mismatch

Answer (score 3):

In most databases, you could do something like this:

```
UPDATE Table
    SET QID = CONCAT(LEFT('QTX0023675', 3), '00', RIGHT('QTX0023675', 5))
    WHERE QID LIKE '________';
```

In any given database, there might be somewhat simpler methods, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLE SET QID= STUFF(QID,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',QID),0,'00')
```